# Handling Json data in snowflake

Tags: sql, json, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ihd9.png)
I have a table which contains Json file data in each row which gets updated into my snowflake table every weak. I am extracting values from the Json files into another table. When the data is loaded in Json format there are multiple entries of the same ID. So, when I extract values from Json to a table there are duplicate rows. How do I tackle them in order to get the distinct rows only. My select query look something like this:

```
select
    json_data:data[0].attributes."Additional Invoice?":: string as "Additional Invoice?",
    json_data:data[0].attributes."Additional PO?":: string as "Additional PO?",
    json_data:data[0].attributes."Aggregate Contract Value":: number as "Aggreagate Contract Value" ,
    json_data:data[0].attributes."Annualized Baseline Spend" :: number as "Annualized Baseline Spend",
    json_data:data[0].id ::number as ID,
    json_data:data[0].type::string as TYPE
   from scout_projects order by ID
```

the scout project file screenshot is attached.
The attached Screenshot is the output form the given query and as you could see the ID column is the same but there are only 2 unique rows. I want my query to return only those 2 unique rows.

```
   select distinct json_data:data[0].id :: number  as ID from scout_projects
```

what is the approach should I take?

I tried using subquery, but it gave me error stating "single-row subquery returns more than one row. snowflake error" which is obvious. so, need a way out .

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output. To resolve duplicates in SQL we use `distinct`, but it is unclear what is duplicate for you.

Comment: Try putting your existing SQL in a CTE and then deduplicate the result in the main SQL statement

Comment: Why do you say "the scout project file screenshot is attached"?

Comment: @astentx I  have attached the screenshot and mentioned the desired output. could you please provide your input?

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all information directly to your question, preferably as editable text